# Shell script to get IPV4 address dynamically and add to route table using cygwin console for windows

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, ipconfig

I am writing a shell script which runs on cygwin console for windows, my scritp looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cmd /c start /d "C:\cygwin\bin" ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"
ipconfig #to print 
route add 10.2.139.1 192.168.104.1
```

But when i execute this script on cygwin console it shows below error and even i changed to ipconfig \all it doesn't work

```
Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.

USAGE:
    ipconfig [/allcompartments] [/? | /all |
```

i am trying to get ip address dynamically by executing the script and adding to the route table

Thanks,
Rohith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you did this with cygwin instead of cmd.exe, what you use it for and why use `start`, but, all you missing is one option `/b`:

```
cmd /c start /d "C:\cygwin\bin" /b ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"
```

And `start` is redudant as follows:

```
cmd /c ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"
```

`/b` just suppresses the newly created `cmd.exe` background window.